# Exception: com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to write my test message to MQ, but failed to do so.

Sharing the source-code and error:

**source-code**

```
import com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQC;

public class MQResponseWriter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;
            MQEnvironment.hostname = "myserver_name";
            MQEnvironment.port = 1417;
            MQEnvironment.channel = "my_channel_name";
            //MQEnvironment.properties.put(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "admin");
            //MQEnvironment.properties.put(CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "passw0rd");          
            //MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);
            MQQueueManager queueManager;
            queueManager = new MQQueueManager("queue_manger_name");
            MQQueue destQueue = queueManager.accessQueue("queue_name", openOptions);
            MQMessage hello_world = new MQMessage();
            hello_world.writeUTF("Blah...blah...bleah...test message no.1...!");
            MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
            destQueue.put(hello_world, pmo);
            destQueue.close();
            queueManager.disconnect();
            System.out.println("------------------------success...");            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**error message**

```
MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2195
MQJE007: IO error reading message data
Error occured during API call - reason code0
MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009
MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2018
Exception: com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:922)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.getConnection(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:426)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:180)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManager.java:771)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.construct(MQQueueManager.java:705)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:434)
    at com.module.main.MQResponseWriter.main(MQResponseWriter.java:24)
```

What might be main cause of above error and solution if any??

Comment: Which line of your program produces the error?  Are there any error messages that show up in the queue managers AMQERR01.LOG at the time you experience the problem? What version of MQ jar files are you use and what version of MQ is on the queue manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how many times I need to post it @ StackOverflow but do NOT use the MQEnvironment class, as it is NOT thread safe.  Use a Hashtable instead.  Here is a working example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC;

/**
 * Program Name
 *  MQTest11
 *
 * Description
 *  This java class will connect to a remote queue manager with the
 *  MQ setting stored in a HashTable and put a message to a queue.
 *
 * Sample Command Line Parameters
 *  -m MQA1 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1414 -c TEST.CHL -q TEST.Q1 -u UserID -x Password
 *
 * @author Roger Lacroix
 */
public class MQTest11
{
   private Hashtable<String,String> params;
   private Hashtable<String,Object> mqht;
   private String qManager;
   private String outputQName;

   /**
    * The constructor
    */
   public MQTest11()
   {
      super();
      params = new Hashtable<String,String>();
      mqht = new Hashtable<String,Object>();
   }

   /**
    * Make sure the required parameters are present.
    * @return true/false
    */
   private boolean allParamsPresent()
   {
      boolean b = params.containsKey("-h") && params.containsKey("-p") &&
                  params.containsKey("-c") && params.containsKey("-m") &&
                  params.containsKey("-q") &&
                  params.containsKey("-u") && params.containsKey("-x");
      if (b)
      {
         try
         {
            Integer.parseInt((String) params.get("-p"));
         }
         catch (NumberFormatException e)
         {
            b = false;
         }
      }

      return b;
   }

   /**
    * Extract the command-line parameters and initialize the MQ HashTable.
    * @param args
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException
    */
   private void init(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException
   {
      int port = 1414;
      if (args.length > 0 && (args.length % 2) == 0)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2)
         {
            params.put(args[i], args[i + 1]);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      if (allParamsPresent())
      {
         qManager = (String) params.get("-m");
         outputQName = (String) params.get("-q");

         try
         {
            port = Integer.parseInt((String) params.get("-p"));
         }
         catch (NumberFormatException e)
         {
            port = 1414;
         }

         mqht.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, params.get("-c"));
         mqht.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, params.get("-h"));
         mqht.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, new Integer(port));
         mqht.put(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, params.get("-u"));
         mqht.put(CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, params.get("-x"));

         // I don't want to see MQ exceptions at the console.
         MQException.log = null;
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
   }

   /**
    * Connect, open queue, write a message, close queue and disconnect.
    *
    * @throws MQException
    */
   private void testSend()
   {
      MQQueueManager qMgr = null;
      MQQueue queue = null;
      String line;
      int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
      MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();

      try
      {
         qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, mqht);
         System.out.println("MQTest11 successfully connected to "+ qManager);

         queue = qMgr.accessQueue(outputQName, openOptions);
         System.out.println("MQTest11 successfully opened "+ outputQName);

         // Define a simple MQ message, and write some text in UTF format..
         MQMessage sendmsg = new MQMessage();
         sendmsg.format = CMQC.MQFMT_STRING;
         sendmsg.feedback = CMQC.MQFB_NONE;
         sendmsg.messageType = CMQC.MQMT_DATAGRAM;

         line = "This is a test message embedded in the MQTest11 program.";

         sendmsg.messageId = CMQC.MQMI_NONE;
         sendmsg.correlationId = CMQC.MQCI_NONE;
         sendmsg.writeString(line);

         // put the message on the queue

         queue.put(sendmsg, pmo);
         System.out.println("Message Data>>>" + line);
      }
      catch (MQException e)
      {
         System.out.println("MQTest11 cc=" +e.completionCode + " : rc=" + e.reasonCode);
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         System.out.println("MQTest11 IOException:" +e.getLocalizedMessage());
      }
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            queue.close();
            System.out.println("MQTest11 closed: "+ outputQName);
         }
         catch (MQException e)
         {
            System.out.println("MQTest11 cc=" +e.completionCode + " : rc=" + e.reasonCode);
         }
         try
         {
            qMgr.disconnect();
            System.out.println("MQTest11 disconnected from "+ qManager);
         }
         catch (MQException e)
         {
            System.out.println("MQTest11 cc=" +e.completionCode + " : rc=" + e.reasonCode);
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * main line
    * @param args
    */
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      MQTest11 write = new MQTest11();

      try
      {
         write.init(args);
         write.testSend();
      }
      catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
      {
         System.err.println("Usage: java MQTest11 -m QueueManagerName -h host -p port -c channel -q QueueName -u UserID -x Password");
         System.exit(1);
      }

      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```