# How come this code works when I run it normally in Android Studio as Java, but as soon as I run it as an app it shows me a NullPointerExcception?

Tags: ibm-mq

It works perfectly fine when it's run normally as a java code, but as soon as it's run as an app, the queueManager shows NULL. All this code is put inside onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState). When it's run as java, the debugger actually shows a queueManager value.

```
void init() {


        int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE | CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF;
        MQEnvironment.hostname = HOST;
        MQEnvironment.channel = CHANNEL;
        MQEnvironment.port = PORT;
        MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);
        MQEnvironment.properties.put(CMQC.THREAD_AFFINITY_PROPERTY, new Boolean(true));

        try {
            queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QMGR);
            System.out.println("Successfully connected to " +  queueManager.getName());
            defaultQueue = queueManager.accessQueue(QUEUE_NAME,openOptions);
            System.out.println("Queue size: " + defaultQueue.getCurrentDepth());

        } catch (MQException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(2);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (queueManager != null);
                queueManager.disconnect();
            } catch (MQException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if (defaultQueue != null);
                defaultQueue.close();
            } catch (MQException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the MQEnvironment a external library? If yes, have you imported it to your android project?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I wouldn't even be able to run it

Answer (score 0):

(1) As I have posted here many times, do NOT use MQEnvironment class as it is not thread safe.  Put the connection information into a Hashtable and pass the Hastable to the MQQueueManager class.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536184/exception-com-ibm-mq-mqexception-mqje001-completion-code-2-reason-2009/49542650#49542650) for an example of what I'm talking about.

(2) Putting "System.exit(2);" in the middle of your code is bad form and that means the finally clause will not be called.  Hence, the code will leave open the queue and connection to queue manager.

(3) In your finally clause, you have the "disconnect" and "close" backwards.  You must close the queue ***before*** you disconnect from the queue manager.