# Dealing with incorrect correlationID in Camel via WMQ

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, ibm-mq

I'm attempting to use camel to be a broker for messages for an external http request to print, which are then printed requests using documaker. The communication between documaker and camel has to be MQ, as it is a production system (Oracle does not support http and we already have a websphere MQ setup).

Now, I'm not sure if this is a linux bug, documaker bug, whatever, but documaker's out of the box client is not responding with the correct correlationID when using temporary queues (though it does use the right queue to respond). It for some reason is returning the hex encoding of the correlation ID instead of the correct version.

This is being done using spring and Camel 2.12.3 (I know, it's a very old version but it's the current supported one in my company).

So my camelroute can send a message, have it received, processed, and then put back on the temporary response queue.
The issue is that while it gets the response, it ignores it, and I'm unsure how to fix this.

My questions are twofold -
What do I need to do to get Camel to understand the returned requestId? It appears to be some sort of transformed string.

The second (for if the previous part is impossible/just for testing) is it possible to make the InOut route accept the first response it receives regardless of request ID?

Route :

```
            from(httpEndpoint)
            .onException(Exception.class)
                .handled(true)
                .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR,
                    "${property._requestSummary} exception=${exception.message} 
            ${exception.stacktrace}")                
            .end()           
            .marshal(documakerJaxb)
            .to("xslt:META-INF/xslt/documaker.xsl")       
             // strips non unicode characters and sets header of IDS
            .processRef("controlCharacterProcessor")
            .processRef("onlineCreateMessageProcessor")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class,StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
            .to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
            // may be unnecessary /
            .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut) 
            .to(ExchangePattern.InOut,documakerEndpoint())
            .to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
        .end();
```

We have a custom MQDestinationResolver that appends the following options to the destination:

```
private int ccsid = 819;

    private int encoding = JMSC.MQJMS_ENCODING_NATIVE;

    private int failIfQuiesce = JMSC.MQJMS_FIQ_YES;

    private int targetClient = JMSC.MQJMS_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ;
```

Endpoint is set via JNDI and looks like this:

```
            dest = lookup(TOMCAT_JNDI_LOOKUP_PREFIX + destinationName,
                    Destination.class);
```

The endpoint looks like this in the route :

```
    protected String documakerEndpoint() {
        return "jms:queue:jms/documakerRequest?preserveMessageQos=true&useMessageIDAsCorrelationID=true"
                + "&receiveTimeout=100&replyToCacheLevelName=CACHE_SESSION&recoveryInterval=100&" + "requestTimeout=30000");
```

the JMS options :

```
    JmsComponent jmsConfiguration() throws JMSException {
        JmsComponent jms = new JmsComponent();        
        jms.setConnectionFactory(queueConnectionFactoryDataSource());
        jms.setDestinationResolver(CustomDestinationResolver());
        jms.setQueueBrowseStrategy(null);        
        jms.setExceptionListener(new JmsExceptionListener());
        jms.setCacheLevelName("CACHE_SESSION");
        jms.setAcknowledgementModeName("AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE");
        jms.setUseMessageIDAsCorrelationID(true);
        return jms;
    }
```

Here's the DM output for the correlationID

```
2021-06-18 20:50:13,629-DEBUG-[IDS-1-ResultSender#1]-[?:?]-com.docucorp.messaging.mqseries.DSIMQMessageQueue.putMessage: [S] - putMessage - messageID=<GDEV9e055d84-b308-4f79-a8b7-2bbc5ee2332f>
2021-06-18 20:50:13,630-DEBUG-[IDS-1-ResultSender#1]-[?:?]-com.docucorp.messaging.mqseries.DSIMQMessageQueue.putMessage: [S] - putMessage - message.messageId=<GDEV9e055d84-b308-4f79-a8b7-2bbc5ee2332f>
2021-06-18 20:50:13,631-DEBUG-[IDS-1-ResultSender#1]-[?:?]-com.docucorp.messaging.mqseries.DSIMQMessageQueue.putMessage: [S] - putMessage - message.correlationId=<GDEV9e055d84-b308-4f79-a8b7-2bbc5ee2332f>
2021-06-18 20:50:13,633-DEBUG-[IDS-1-ResultSender#1]-[?:?]-com.docucorp.messaging.mqseries.DSIMQMessageQueue.putMessage: [S] - putMessage - replyToQueueManagerName=<CSQ1> replyToQueueName=<AMQ.D9E20BE21954DB0A>
```

What camel sees after this :

```
2021-06-18 16:50:13,798 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager  - Bound value [org.springframework.jms.listener.LocallyExposedJmsResourceHolder@7025d428] for key [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory@c1671d89] to thread [Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - TemporaryQueueReplyManager[jms/documakerRequest]]
2021-06-18 16:50:13,799 org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyManager  - Received reply message with correlationID [ID:4744455639653035356438342d623330382d346637392d61] -> 
JMS Message class: jms_text
  JMSType:         null
  JMSDeliveryMode: 1
  JMSExpiration:   1624051213793
  JMSPriority:     0
  JMSMessageID:    ID:4744455639653035356438342d623330382d346637392d61
  JMSTimestamp:    1624049382840
  JMSCorrelationID:ID:4744455639653035356438342d623330382d346637392d61
  JMSDestination:  null
  JMSReplyTo:      null
  JMSRedelivered:  false
  JMS_IBM_PutDate:20210618
  JMSXAppID:WebSphere MQ Client for Java
  JMS_IBM_Format:MQSTR   
  JMS_IBM_PutApplType:28
  JMS_IBM_MsgType:8
  JMSXUserID:CSQ1CHIN    
  JMS_IBM_PutTime:20494284
  JMSXDeliveryCount:1
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_Part_0_4067192.1624049413605"

------=_Part_0_40671
Another 32,226 character(s) omitted
2021-06-18 16:50:13,799 org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyManager  - Reply received for unknown correlationID [ID:4744455639653035356438342d623330382d346637392d61]. The message will be ignored: 
JMS Message class: jms_text
  JMSType:         null
  JMSDeliveryMode: 1
  JMSExpiration:   1624051213793
  JMSPriority:     0
  JMSMessageID:    ID:4744455639653035356438342d623330382d346637392d61
  JMSTimestamp:    1624049382840
  JMSCorrelationID:ID:4744455639653035356438342d623330382d346637392d61
  JMSDestination:  null
  JMSReplyTo:      null
  JMSRedelivered:  false
  JMS_IBM_PutDate:20210618
  JMSXAppID:WebSphere MQ Client for Java
  JMS_IBM_Format:MQSTR   
  JMS_IBM_PutApplType:28
  JMS_IBM_MsgType:8
  JMSXUserID:CSQ1CHIN    
  JMS_IBM_PutTime:20494284
  JMSXDeliveryCount:1
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_Part_0_4067192.1624049413605"

------=_Part_0_40671
Another 32,226 character(s) omitted
2021-06-18 16:50:13,799 org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager  - Removed value [org.springframework.jms.listener.LocallyExposedJmsResourceHolder@7025d428] for key [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory@c1671d89] from thread [Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - TemporaryQueueReplyManager[jms/documakerRequest]]
2021-06-18 16:50:24,463 org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap  - Evicting inactive entry ID: Camel-ID-XXXX022522-51024-1624049349742-0-6 (times out after 30000 millis)
```

QCF and channel setup in tomcat

```
Server.XML
 <Resource CHAN="Channel2" HOST="x.x.mlan" PORT="1415" QMGR="CSQ1" TRAN="1" UCP="true" XAEnabled="false" auth="Container" description="Queue Connection Factory" factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory" name="jms/queueConnectionFactory" targetClient="JMS" transportType="CLIENT" type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"/> 
 <Resource QU="ENV.DM.REQ" auth="Container" description="Queue for sending Request to Documaker" factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueFactory" name="jms/documakerRequest" targetClient="MQ" type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue"/>
```

Update: I've fixed the invalid characters issue. I was using jars from Oracle which were for a windows machine on a Linux machine. Now they are readable but my camelroute is reading them differently. (Camel is windows machine, Documaker is RHEL 6.10)

Comment: MQMD MsgId, CorrelId and GroupId fields are all byte array fields of 24 bytes.  So, yes, it will look like garbage if you try and treat those fields as a String.  Dump out those fields in HEX and see if it matches what you are looking for.  If you don't know how to do it then check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64117972/ways-to-convert-bytes-to-string/64127533#64127533

Comment: Can you also update your question with the value (in hex) of the request message's Message ID, so we can compare what went out with what is coming back in the Correlation ID.

Comment: I realized I was using an outdated client library from Oracle. I've updated that and it now looks like the hex thing you guys were saying. I'll add details to the parent.

Comment: @MoragHughson I've added the value and what camel is sending and seeing/what dm is seeing and sending. It's a java generated UUID appended to a common value.

It definitely looks like some sort of issue where camel isn't converting from hex, as the value camel see is the hex value of what is sent, though only a portion due to length.